# Inference results depend on order of images in training batch

Tags: tensorflow

I've trained the same network two times on the same dataset of 5 images. For the first time, the images in a batch for each step were in the same order. For the second time, the batch was shuffled before every training step. Both models overfit. Both models were tested on shuffled images from training dataset.
The firs model shows 100% accuracy.
```

```
Prediction  Labels
[6 1 4 3 7] [6 1 4 3 7]
[3 4 1 7 6] [3 4 1 7 6]
[6 1 4 3 7] [6 1 4 3 7]
[4 3 7 6 1] [4 3 7 6 1]
[4 7 6 3 1] [4 7 6 3 1]
[1 3 7 6 4] [1 3 7 6 4]
[3 1 6 7 4] [3 1 6 7 4]
```

```

The second model shows accuracy close to a random guess.
```

```
Prediction  Labels
[1 4 3 6 7] [7 4 6 3 1]
[3 6 4 1 7] [7 4 3 1 6]
[1 6 3 7 4] [1 6 4 3 7]
[4 7 3 6 1] [1 6 4 3 7]
[3 6 7 4 1] [4 1 3 7 6]
[1 3 7 4 6] [6 3 4 7 1]
[1 4 7 3 6] [3 7 1 4 6]
```

```

Related issues - none

#### Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
- CUDA 8.0
- cuDNN 5.1
- tensorflow 0.12.1 from pip with GPU support

#### Dataset

5 images from MNIST

#### The attached archive

contains code for reproducible example.

- runner.py is responsible for preparing image batches and maintains the queue.
- network.py contains the code of simple neural network(2 convolutional layers with relu activation, softmax output layer)
- train_not_shuffled.py trains and tests the network using non-shuffled batch
- train_shuffled.py trains and tests the network using shuffled batch

[example.gz](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/files/735318/example.gz)

I've retrained the models several times, tried different datasets and network architectures. I've visualized graph to make sure inference uses the same variables. I've also visualized weights, they look slightly different for two cases but don't contain any anomalies that could explain such behavior.

Comment: You say both models overfit, so they both get close to 100% accuracy on training data? I would consider that you are comparing against wrong labels in testing, ie output the prediction of the model and look at the image it was looking at, and classify it manually

Comment: I use the same code to test both models, so labels would be mixed in both cases. Actually, wrong order of labes or some error in shuffling were my first guess, so I double checked those.

Comment: You have that both models overfit, which implies they get close to perfect on training set. But then you say that you tested on your training set and get close to random. So it's confusing what you tested it on

Comment: Suggestions what to check: - use the training dataset for testing in both cases. In specific, use an identical copy. Then, the accuracy of testing should match the accuracy for training. - change your batch size to 1 for testing. Does the accuracy depend on the batch size? Unless you do not use batch normalization or other algorithms making use of batch statistics, this may give further insights.

Comment: Training and testing images get to network through differrent paths. Training images are taken fron queue while test images get to placeholder through feed dict. This can explain why inference results are differrent from training, but not why they depend on order in training batches.

Comment: @gizzmole I've changed the test batch size, nothing changed. As well, I've previously tried train batch of size 10 with no changes. The code published here does not use batch normalization, but I've tested all this with several networks tat did use batch norm with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was in the testing code. This lines

```
images_batch = images_batch.eval()
labels_batch = labels_batch.eval()
```

run separately, so images and labels were actually from different batches. If batches were identical, labels correspond to images and testing results were perfect. On the other hand, when batches were shuffled, test predictions were compared to wrong labels, so the results were poor.
Replacing the two lines above with

```
images_batch, labels_batch = sess.run(train_runner.get_inputs())
```

fixed the problem.